# transform multiple columns to single row in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 1000 IDs and their values. What would be better way to convert two columns into single row based on ID. I used cast function from reshape package but it seems to convert only one column into row. Here is an example of my dataset.

```
DF <- data.frame(ID=c("x1","x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2","x2"),
      name1=c("T1","T1","T2","T2","T1","T1","T2","T2"),
      name2=c("C1","C2","C1","C2","C1","C2","C1","C2"),T1_val=c(1.1,1.1,2.3,2.3,1.8,1.8,7.9,7.9),C1_val=c(1.1,2.6,1.1,2.6,1.8,3.6,1.8,3.6) )

 > DF
 ID name1 name2 T1_val C1_val
 x1    T1    C1    1.1    1.1
 x1    T1    C2    1.1    2.6
 x1    T2    C1    2.3    1.1
 x1    T2    C2    2.3    2.6                
 x2    T1    C1    1.8    1.8
 x2    T1    C2    1.8    3.6
 x2    T2    C1    7.9    1.8
 x2    T2    C2    7.9    3.6
```

Desired output:

```
ID  T1   T2   C1   C2
x1  1.1  2.3  1.1  2.6
x2  1.8  7.9  1.8  3.6
```

Thanks

Comment: Please see the output section. I have just given example of two IDs here

Comment: Your desired output contains only 8 values while you expect to see 16, no?

Comment: No. You will see that for ID "x1" T1 or T2 has same value in T1_val column  or C1_val and same goes for ID "x2". That is the reason for having 8 values in  result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the dplyr and tidyr combo pretty straightforward:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>%
  spread(name1, T1_val) %>%
  spread(name2, C1_val)
```

produces

```
Source: local data table [2 x 5]

  ID  T1  T2  C1  C2
1 x1 1.1 2.3 1.1 2.6
2 x2 1.8 7.9 1.8 3.6
```

PS: Take a look at this [cheatsheet](http://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf) if you want to dig into these packages.

Comment: Nice solution. Wouldn't think of it. You don't need `tbl_dt(DF)` though

Comment: @pfuhlert Thank you. With my orignal dataset I get the following error                                            Error in dim(ordered) <- c(attr(row_id, "n"), attr(col_id, "n")) : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Then I can have a look.

On googling the error, I found this: https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/36
Does it help?

Comment: Sorry I wrote a wrong column name thats why this error was generated